# Create Python Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
a_lst = list()
b_lst = list()
tmp = list()
c_dct = dict()
while True:
   a = raw_input("a=")
   a_lst.append(a)
   b = raw_input("b=")
   b_lst.append(b)
   if a == "end":
      break
a_lst.remove('end')
print a_lst
print b_lst


for i in range(len(a_lst)):
   c_dct[a_lst[i]] = b_lst[i] 


print c_dct
```

In this code, I combine 2 lists to create the dictionary. In the result, the dictionary is not the same position as the input. 
For example,

```
c_dct = {'q': 'w', 'e': 'r', 'o': 'p', '1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6', 't': 'y', '7': '8', '9': '0', 'u': 'i'}
```

instead of

```
c_dct =  {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6','7': '8', '9': '0','q': 'w', 'e': 'r','t': 'y','u': 'i','o': 'p'}
```

What is going on the code?
How to slove this problem?
Thank You very much!

Comment: Why don't you check if `a == "end"` *before* adding it to the list (or before asking for another `b` value, for that matter)?

Answer (score 6):

Dictionaries do not maintain order by default. If you need an ordered dictionary, you can use the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are *unordered* by design. So, everything is OK and you can't create a perfectly ordered dictionary.

Here is a quote from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) (section 5.5):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered** set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).